# Meteor: How do I prevent people from using commands from console

Tags: meteor

I want to prevent people from doing commands like Meteor.user(), (dbname).find().fetch(), etc

**I have removed the insecure & autopublish package**

But you can still do the commands like Meteor.user(), and you can still see all the items you have access to in a db.

My Question: *is there any way to prevent the users from running said commands?*

Comment: No. Basic principle of js - you can run whatever commands are available in the browser from the console. You need to remove `autopublish` as well and then start reading about Meteor security best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is an issue with web development in general, everything on the client system, the client has access too. If you are insuring they only have access to the data they should, and that all operations on the data are checked on the server side for security, there is nothing bad they can do from the console, so it doesn't matter.